# Formatting HTML generated from PHP in Wordpress theme for site text logo

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm setting up a website using a Wordpress theme that has built in options for graphic and text logos. I want to use the built in text logo feature but I want to break the logo apart so multiple fonts and formatting could be used in the logo.

The header.php file calls the logo using this code:

```
    <?php napoli_site_logo(); ?>
```

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
    <a href="http://www.psphotography.com/" class="logo">
         <span>Paige Stumbo</span>      </a>
```

It pulls the logo text from a field in the theme setup and references *.right-menu .logo span* in the main CSS to get it's formatting.

To duplicate the logo I take the HTML from above and put it in the header.php file under

```
    <?php napoli_site_logo(); ?>
```

I changed the HTML for the class= to reference "logo1" instead of logo then duplicated all the *.right-menu .logo span* in the CSS file and changed it to *.logo1* instead.

This gave me the result I was looking for, two separate text logos are now visible on the homepage side by side.

[image]

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
    <!-- LOGO -->
    <a href="http://www.psphotography.com/" class="logo">
         <span>Paige Stumbo</span>      </a>
    <a href="http://www.psphotography.com/" class="logo1">
         <span>PHOTOGRAPHY</span>       </a>
    <!-- /LOGO -->
```

How do I get the second logo below the first instead of side by side? I know how to achieve this with basic HTML formatting but since the HTML is being generated from PHP I'm lost.

Comment: just make `<a>` with `display:block`. something like: `.logo, .logo1{display: block;}` . of course, it may been overriden from other rules. but this must work

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following CSS:

```
.logo {
  display: block !important; 
}
.logo1 {
  display:block !important; 
}
```

Fiddle showing it working: 
https://jsfiddle.net/tet4djoc/

Comment: Yeah that didn't work, something else must be overriding it or something.

Comment: @tim829 then you should provide more details, such as css rules, which are overriding this one. we can't guess, how is your markup and styling rules

Comment: The CSS doesn't read as just .logo1, it's actually .right-menu .logo1 span. So my best guess would be something with the .right-menu is overriding the modifications I try to set on .logo1